# com4j works in eclipse but not working in jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, hp-quality-center, com4j

I wrote a tool (using **spring boot**) to get the details from **HP QC v10**. I'm using **com4j** API for this. Program works fine in **eclipse** but throws following **Exception** when I'm running code through **jar** (which I have created using **maven** install).

I have generated the wrapper for **OTAClient.dll** and made **jar** file of wrapper **qcconn.jar**. Also I have registered the dll files : **OTAClient.dll, WebClient.dll** and **com4j-amd64.dll**. I'm using **jdk 8** (32 bit).

I checked **jar** file of my tool which was generated by **maven** install and it has both **jar** included in it : **com4j.jar** and **qcconn.jar**.

Exception is thrown when I ran jar file : **java -jar mytool.jar**

`````
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1295) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at com.qc.ClassFactory.createTDConnection(ClassFactory.java:16) ~[qcconn-1.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.qc.report.gen.app.qc.connection.QCTool.<init>(QCTool.java:23) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com4j.COM4J.loadNativeLibrary(COM4J.java:567) ~[com4j-1.0.jar!/:na]
        at com4j.COM4J.<clinit>(COM4J.java:522) ~[com4j-1.0.jar!/:na]
        ... 47 common frames omitted

Exception in thread "Com4J shutdown hook" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com4j.COM4J
        at com4j.COM4J$3.run(COM4J.java:476)````
`````

Answer (score 1):

As I was using 32 bit JVM, everytime I was missing to register com4j-x86.dll.
After registering it. It started to work.
Also please make sure when running jar, following dll file should be present under same folder where jar is present : com4j-x86.dll, OTAClient.dll and WebClient.dll